# How to compare time/dates in string form?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm working on a basic program that starts a process based on a timestamp saved in a text file.

I use the following format to save the time/date into the text file:

```
strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",localtime())
```

Later I will read the file, and if the current time > timestamp + a preset delta (in minutes) then I will move to the next part of the script.

I'm currently handling this 100% by myself and I have written a function that splits the string and the delta both into minutes, hours, days, months, and years and adds them together.

I'm wondering is there a quicker way to do this? Does python offer an easier solution that I missed?

I'm not attached to the current formatting of the time and date and I'm willing to format it differently so long as the functionality is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strftime has an opposite that converts strings into datetime objects - strptime, so in your case you can do this:

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    date_from_file = datetime.strptime(string_from_file, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

also, notice that i also imported "timedelta", which you can use like this:

```
    if datetime.now() > date_from_file + timedelta(hours=3):
        do_something()
```

which will check if the current time is greater than the time 3 hours after the time in the file. of course you can change

```
    timedelta(hours=3)
```

to

```
    timedelta(minutes=15)
```

or whatever else you need...

i recommend learning more on timedelta if you need anything more: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html